# How to create .htaccess for multiple parameters in URL?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need using this .htaccess file. It only changes the URL from [www.mydomain.com/users/user?usernam=myname123&profile=myprofile123&data=mydata123](http://www.mydomain.com/users/user?usernam=myname123&profile=myprofile123&data=mydata123) to [www.example.com/users/myname123/myprofile123/mydata123](http://www.example.com/users/myname123/myprofile123/mydata123) .

i use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\-_.]*)/?$ /users/user.php?username=$1&profile=$2&data=$3[L,QSA]
```

htaccess in users folder

not work

Comment: complete,
 path     /users/.htaccess ,
i have another htaccess in home path

Comment: As per [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283057/mod-rewrite-questions-getting-migrated-to-sf) and [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283033/are-htaccess-questions-ever-on-topic-at-so) this question is not at all off-topic for SO so close vote is wrong. This has been discussed again and again and it has been settled already that most of the rewrite rules are created and maintained by developers of the web applications/frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following rules. This will take anything in REQUEST_URI starting.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?\s 
RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1?username=%2&profile=%3&data=%4 [NE,L,NC]
```

OR(either use above or following one) in case you want to match `users` in URI then run rules then try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /users/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?\s 
RewriteRule ^(.*) /users?username=%1&profile=%2&data=%3 [NE,L,NC]
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

- `RewriteEngine ON`: Enabling RewriteEngine here to enable mod rule writing.
- `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$`: Checking condition if query string is NULL then go further in rules.
- `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /users/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?\s`: Matching regex in `THE_REQUEST` from `/users` to till spaces and capturing 3 groups values into back references to be used later.
- `RewriteRule ^(.*) /users?username=%1&profile=%2&data=%3 [NE,L,NC]`: Using url rewrite to change URI to as per OP's request which has back references values in it.